# OpenIddict - hosting auth server and web api resource in same project

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, .net-core, openiddict

I want to implement an OpenIdConnect/Oauth2 server using OpenIddict in order to secure a .NET core API app.  Most examples I have seen implement these as separate projects.

The client app is a SPA and we are using implicit flow.

I have based my solution on the code shown in the OpenIddict samples here:
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples

For the project I am working on it would ideally have the Auth server and API to use the same port and be in the same project.  ( One of the customer's requirements is that they don't want another server to configure since they own the API resource and it will be on the same server)

I have configured OpenIddict and combined it with our API project.  Almost everything works correctly - the API endpoints are protected with the [Authorize] attribute and prevent access to protected API end points.  However, when the API resource is protected, instead of returning a 401 Unauthorized HTTP status code, the returned result is the HTML Login page of the Auth server itself.

Here is the relevant setup code in my Startup.cs file:

```
 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");
        //app.UseCors(builder =>
        //{
        //    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();//)WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        //    builder.WithMethods("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
        //    builder.WithHeaders("Authorization");
        //});

        app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), branch =>
        {
            branch.UseIdentity();
        });

        app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), branch =>
        {
            branch.UseOAuthValidation();

        });

        app.UseOpenIddict();


        #region Adding resource config here (api)
        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

        app.UseOAuthIntrospection(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
            options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
            options.Audiences.Add("resource-server-1");
            options.ClientId = "resource-server-1";
            options.ClientSecret = "846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342";
        });

        //app.UseCors(builder => {
        //    builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
        //    builder.WithMethods("GET");
        //    builder.WithHeaders("Authorization");
        //});
        #endregion


        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        // Seed the database with the sample applications.
        // Note: in a real world application, this step should be part of a setup script.
        InitializeAsync(app.ApplicationServices, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    }

private async Task InitializeAsync(IServiceProvider services, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Create a new service scope to ensure the database context is correctly disposed when this methods returns.
        using (var scope = services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

            var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<OpenIddictApplicationManager<OpenIddictApplication>>();

            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("MySPA", cancellationToken) == null)
            {
                var application = new OpenIddictApplication
                {
                    ClientId = "MySPA",
                    DisplayName = "MySPA",
                    LogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:9000/signout-oidc",
                    RedirectUri = "http://localhost:9000/signin-oidc"
                };

                await manager.CreateAsync(application, cancellationToken);
            }

            if (await manager.FindByClientIdAsync("resource-server-1", cancellationToken) == null)
            {
                var application = new OpenIddictApplication
                {
                    ClientId = "resource-server-1"
                };

                await manager.CreateAsync(application, "846B62D0-DEF9-4215-A99D-86E6B8DAB342", cancellationToken);
            }

        }
    }
```

Not sure how to implement these both side by side in the same project. As mentioned it all "works" except the API is returning the HTML login page and not a desired HTTP status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.UseIdentity();` is present twice in your pipeline, which defeats the whole purpose of using `branch.UseIdentity()` in a `app.UseWhen()` branching builder (i.e making sure the cookies middleware registered by Identity are not invoked for your API endpoints).

Remove the first occurrence and it should work.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem - works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 1):

You set the AutomaticChallenge to `true`. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie)

> this flag indicates that the middleware should redirect the browser to the LoginPath or AccessDeniedPath when authorization fails.

So by setting this to false it will not redirect to the login.